# AIC for different variables

Tags: model-selection, aic, information-criteria

I have been wondering, can AIC be safely used for model selection when the datasets contain a different number of variables? What I mean is, can a model predicting house price that contains "surface in $m^2$" be compared with a model containing "surface in $m^2$" **and** "number of rooms" safely?

And if not, which IC should I use for this problem?

The thing is I have seen contradictory information online and I'm not sure how to interpret it anymore.

Comment: I think this is exactly how the stepwise regression works. In R, the function is even called `stepAIC()`

Comment: Yes, for sure, in fact AIC exists in order to help us choose between models with different numbers of parameters (do consider AICc instead tho).